# Hibernate: how do you adjust the default logging level (SJF4J and JDK 1.4 logger)?

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, slf4j, java.util.logging

I have a JavaSE/Hibernate test app (shell-based). I put the following JARs into the project's lib dir:

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate3.jar
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
jta-1.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar
```

As you can see, I'm using SLF4J with the JDK 1.4 logger. When I run my test app from the shell, Hibernate is very verbose because it is set to the INFO level by default:

```
09.12.2010 02:23:14 org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
09.12.2010 02:23:14 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.6.0.Final
09.12.2010 02:23:14 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
09.12.2010 02:23:14 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : javassist
09.12.2010 02:23:14 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
09.12.2010 02:23:14 org.hibernate.ejb.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate EntityManager 3.6.0.Final
09.12.2010 02:23:15 org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: tld.standalone.bbstats.model.Game
09.12.2010 02:23:15 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
INFO: Bind entity tld.standalone.bbstats.model.Game on table Games
09.12.2010 02:23:15 org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: tld.standalone.bbstats.model.Roster
09.12.2010 02:23:15 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
INFO: Bind entity tld.standalone.bbstats.model.Roster on table Rosters
.
.
.
```

How do I adjust the Hibernate logging level, to say WARNING?

EclipseLink for example let's you specify the level via a property (persistence.xml):

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE" />
```

Is there an equivalent in Hibernate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would always prefer to configure the logging framework with a central configuration file instead of several specific logging settings of libraries, because that's one of the reasons to use a logging framework at all.

Hibernate seems to [follow that philosophy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-logging) and since you are using JDK logging just [configure the log level with a property file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).

Answer (score 4):

In my logging.properties file, I set:

```
org.hibernate.SQL.level=FINEST // Show SQL statements
org.hibernate.type.level=FINEST // Show the bind parameter values
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to stop hibernate being so verbose is to add `log4j-over-slf4j.jar` to your classpath. That's because hibernate uses log4j for logging, and when you add that jar all the logging intentend to go through log4j will be redirected to slf4j.